# Cannot change a file to untracked

Tags: git

I have tried reset but it doesn't work.how to change a file to untracked?

```
git status
   untracked files:
   bin
   gen

git add gen
git status
   untracked files:
   bin

git reset gen
git status
   untracked files:
   bin
```

it doesn't work.is the command right?how to change a file to untracked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git rm --cache gen
```

does not delete the file, but change to untracked

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using ?

```
git rm gen
```

I think that is what you want. Or you can simply rm the file. This will remove the file, but if it is on a different branch then you change branch and it will return. Alternatively you could mv the file out of the tracked directory if you are worried about losing it ie.

```
mv gen /tmp
```

I also recommend using gitx app strongly you can just shift things from stagged to unstagged with a double click.